# Problems working with dependent values from HTML to Spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, range

I am working on a dynamic dependent dropdown, and I have gotten very far and learned alot through stackoverflow, so thanks to everyone. Anyways Iv'e reached a stopping point where something isn't working?

Here is a url for the online script: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzWi3JymieWMAGVLQVl2xEXCd_eo85hWercHAFkNrqH5dkvWWQd/exec

and a url to the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BK5urtTzqZ2kc89ZnbeMSIm2-bt4KLNTQghsxn0cXBI/edit#gid=0

Two lists are generated the first one lists all the sheets in the spreadsheet, and the second one, should, list the values in the first row.

So below you see my index.html:

**index.html**

```
<div>
<select id="categories" onchange="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildSubCategoriesList)
  .getSubCategories()">
<option>Loading...</option>    
</select>

<select id="subCategories">
<option>Loading...</option>    
</select>

</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
// This code in this function runs when the page is loaded.
$(function() {
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildCategoriesList)
  .getCategories();
});

function buildCategoriesList(sheetsName) {
var list = $('#categories');
list.empty();
for (var i = 0; i < sheetsName.length; i++) {
list.append('<option value="' + sheetsName[i] + '">' + sheetsName[i] + '</option>');
}
}
</script>

<script>
function buildSubCategoriesList(columnsName) {
var list = $('#subCategories');
list.empty();
for (var i = 0; i < columnsName.length; i++) {
list.append('<option value="' + columnsName[i] + '">' + columnsName[i] + '</option>');
}
}
</script>
```

and here is the code:

**code.gs**

```
function doGet(request) {
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index')
  .evaluate()
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function include(filename) {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
  .getContent();
}

var ss   =  SpreadsheetApp.openById("1BK5urtTzqZ2kc89ZnbeMSIm2-bt4KLNTQghsxn0cXBI");

function getCategories(){
sheetsName = [];
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
for( var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++ ){
  sheetsName .push(sheets[i].getName() )
};
return sheetsName;
}

function getSubCategories(categories){
columnsName = [];
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(categories);
var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
var subRange = sheet.getRange("A1"+lastCol);
var columns = subRange.getValues;

for( var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++ ){
  columnsName .push(columns[i])
};
return columnsName;
}
```

I have tried alot of things, any I really can't seem to figure out a way to make this work. So I am asking you guys, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things have to be corrected in your code for it to work:

- **index.html file:** your call to `getSubCategories()` function in onchange event on categories select did not pass the selected value
- **index.html file:** populating a `<select>` element with options does not trigger change event - thus you need to trigger it manually to update Sub-categories select
- **code.gs file:** in `getSubCategories()` function, your `getRange()` call retrieved 3 rows in column A instead of 3 cell in row 1
- **code.gs file:** again in `getSubCategories()` function your *getValues* call has to be `getValues()`; and since `getValues()` returns a 2D array, you have to get column values from the first array item only (first row), hence it should be `getValues()[0]`

Corrected working code attached below:

**code.gs**

```
var ss   = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1BK5urtTzqZ2kc89ZnbeMSIm2-bt4KLNTQghsxn0cXBI");

function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index')
      .evaluate()
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function getCategories(){
  var sheetsName = [];
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for( var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++ ){
    sheetsName.push( sheets[i].getName() )
  }
  return sheetsName;
}

function getSubCategories(categories){
  var columnsName = [];
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(categories);
  var subRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  var columns = subRange.getValues()[0]; 

  for( var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++ ){
    columnsName.push( columns[i] )
  }
  return columnsName;
}
```

**index.html**

```
<div>
  <select id="categories" onchange="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildSubCategoriesList)
.getSubCategories(this.value)">
    <option>Loading...</option>    
  </select>

  <select id="subCategories">
    <option>Loading...</option>    
  </select>

</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
// This code in this function runs when the page is loaded.
$(function() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildCategoriesList).getCategories();
});

function buildCategoriesList(sheetsName) {
  var list = $('#categories');
  list.empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheetsName.length; i++) {
    list.append('<option value="' + sheetsName[i] + '">' + sheetsName[i] + '</option>');
  }
  list.trigger("change");
}

function buildSubCategoriesList(columnsName) {
  console.log(columnsName);
  var list = $('#subCategories');
  list.empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < columnsName.length; i++) {
    list.append('<option value="' + columnsName[i] + '">' + columnsName[i] + '</option>');
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much, this was so helpful, really really helpful.